# docker shows no memory release of SQLite database

Tags: linux, performance, sqlite, memory, docker

I am checking the amount of memory that SQLite operations consume (mostly insert).

I run my program on docker container, and inspect the memory usage with `docker stats <container id>`. I observe a weird behavior where the memory usage only grows and doesn't return to normal after the operation has complete.

here is a snippet of the code:

```
conn =  sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('insert into users (uid, full_name, email, username, job_title) values (?,?,?,?,?)', [user_cn, user_full_name, user_email, user_uname, user_jobtitle])
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Its only a snippet (I cutted out most of the code), this procedure takes place thousands of times (commit on every insert, close once at the end).

As I said I observe only an increase in the memory usage on `stats`, another thing I observed is that `top` doesn't show any memory activity (stays 0.1%).

On my research I tried running some dummy operation on the linux:

```
for i in {1..100000}; do echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" >> woot.data; done
```

I observed the same behavior so I guess it's not SQLite's problem but I still include it since its my usecase and maybe its configuration/connection close related stuff.

Any advice on solving this mystery will be highly appreciated!

EDIT: The docker's version is: `Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef/1.5.0`

Answer (score 1):

That can depends on your actual host, and docker version.

For instance:

- With docker 1.11-rc4, memory leaks are reported ([issue 21837](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21837)) and
- on Mac,  docker 1.11.0rc3 contains a bug that doesn't show the memory-limit in stats ([issue 21848](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21848#issuecomment-207716674))

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, the version is 1.5.0. seems like quite a problem if it is the case of memory leak.

Comment: @Anton.P are you using docker 1.5.0?

Comment: yes the version is 1.5.0, `Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef/1.5.0`

Comment: @Anton.P That seems... ancient:) Can you try with docker 1.11-rc4 from 2 days ago?

Comment: unfortunately I can't, its a distant machine not owned by me. Is there any other way to make sure it is a memory leak?

Comment: @Anton.P Then I can only surmise this is related to an *old* docker version bug (I mean: February 2015, https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150-2015-02-10, more than a year ago, a lifetime in docker history).

Comment: thank you very much for trying to help. I added the version in the question and I will try to look for a way to confirm it.